# What to do with a correct one-liner code-only answer?

Tags: discussion

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50485404/3094533) was accepted as correct.
It contains only a line of code (that actually does what the OP is asking) without any explanation whatsoever. Another user commented with a link to a Wikipedia explaining the math behind it, and I've left a comment asking the author of the answer to include some explanation. The answer was not edited, so now I'm wondering what should I do about it.
I mean, one one hand, it does solve the problem, so I don't think I should downvote it or flag it as low quality, but on the other hand, it just throws a line of code, that unless you know the mathematic formula in advance, is anything but self explanatory, so I don't think I should upvote it either.

I could just ignore it, knowing I did my part, but something bugs me about this answer.
I think what bugs me the most about it is that I would like to upvote it, but as it is now I don't think it deserves an upvote.

So after I've already asked nicely for an explanation, what else can I do about it? Should I do anything else?

Comment: You could edit it yourself.

Comment: @AndréKool Editing an answer to significantly change its meaning is not a good idea (except CW). Providing your own answer has many benefits, including letting the community vote on each answer individually.

Comment: Realistically, the answer is sufficient and acceptable as it is. It could use improvement, but if the author thinks it should stand as is then that should be respected. If you want to add another answer which expands on that answer by offering an explanation while citing the source for the code being the other answer, that is acceptable as well.

Comment: vote and move on. (up or down,) or just move on

Comment: @TinyGiant While your comment is, at face value, diametrically opposite to [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368531/2751851), I feel we might be actually arguing from similar vantage points. Let me explain myself better: if an answer with no textual explanation is acceptable as it is, it is likely because the explanation is straightforward and obvious enough to be inferred from the code alone. Part of my point is that, if that is indeed the case, adding the obvious explanation would be a relatively minor change, rather than a radical transformation of the answer.

Comment: If I thought the code was self explanatory I would have no problem upvoting and moving on. I don't think so, hence my dilemma. I think I might just move on without voting.

Comment: In this case, I think a link to a proper explanation and a brief summary of the concept in case the link goes dead would be appropriate, but I do think that should be a separate answer unless the author were to edit it themselves. @duplode

Comment: @ZoharPeled Perhaps "inferred from the code alone" in my comment above was an overstatement. In the concrete case you have brought here, the explanation certainly can't be easily inferred from the code, even though it is obvious what the core explanation should consist of. A more nuanced way of putting it would be saying there is a class of answers for which adding an explanation is mostly an editorial choice, and that it includes a little more than just the truly and literally self-explanatory ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So after I've already asked nicely for an explanation, what else can I do about it? Should I do anything else?

You could always add an answer with an explanation if you are knowledgeable on the subject. Just because the answer is accepted by OP does not mean it is a good/helpful for others. Neither does it mean more posts cannot be added. It means it worked for the asker and nothing more.

Over time the community will decide on the better answer by voting on the posts.

I wouldn't suggest editing the post yourself since you would be changing it more than what the author intended.

Comment: The problem is I wasn't aware of the math this solution is based on, so posting another answer doesn't seem like a good option to me. Also, I don't think I should edit the accepted answer. I know that the fact an answer is accepted doesn't make it a good answer, but I think with proper explanation it could be a very good answer...

Comment: Short of requesting OP.. which you already did I don't think there is  much you can do

Comment: I think what bugs me the most about it is that I would like to upvote it, but as it is now I don't think it deserves an upvote. (edited into my question as well). I guess I just have to let it go, then

Answer (score 2):

If the explanation is straightforward and obvious, and you are confident in your ability to write it in a clear way, editing it into the answer can be a reasonable thing to do -- if that is the case, you can be reasonably sure you won't end up accidentally changing the meaning of the answer.

A few things to keep in mind:

- Adding an explanation is more likely to work well if the answer is simple. In your case, it being a one-liner based on a small nugget of math means the odds of success are good. It would be a riskier move for an answer consisting of a larger code snippet.
- Make your explanation as succinct and to-the-point as possible. This decreases the risk of putting words in the author's mouth. (If you do have a substantial amount of additional things to say that go beyond the minimum necessary to explain the solution, it is better to post your own answer. You can mention the other answer in passing and link to it in order to give it credit for the idea.)
- Leave a comment to the answer explaining what you have done -- it is both courteous and transparent to do so. Here is one way of phrasing it, adapted from past comments of mine:

  > I took the liberty of adding a brief explanatory remark. Feel free to edit it as much as you find appropriate.

In the specific case of your answer, the Wikipedia article linked to in a comment helpfully provides detailed commentary on what is behind the solution. Since it isn't necessary to cover the math in depth in the answer, a minimal explanation can be as straightforward as this:

> The result you are looking for is known as the [digital root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root) of an integer. It can be calculated as follows: [...]